# Html.BeginForm sends null objects to controller with Html.HiddenFor

Tags: asp.net-core, razor

This is my code

```
@model MyModel


@using (Html.BeginForm("Action", "Controller", FormMethod.Post, new { @enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    Html.HiddenFor(x => x.ID);

    <label>Name: </label>@Html.EditorFor(x => x.Name);

    <button>Submit</button>
}
```

for some reason in my controller i get `MyModel` with values of `Name = new name` but `ID = null`

Why this happens?

Answer (score 0):

Reviewing my code one line is problem but doesn't give error:

```
@model MyModel


@using (Html.BeginForm("Action", "Controller", FormMethod.Post, new { @enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    Html.HiddenFor(x => x.ID); // This one

    <label>Name: </label>@Html.EditorFor(x => x.Name);

    <button>Submit</button>
}
```

Solution is simple if you know what may be problem but if you do not you will not solve it since it doesn't drop error.

Solution was adding `@` before `Html.HiddenFor(x => x.ID);`.

```
@model MyModel


@using (Html.BeginForm("Action", "Controller", FormMethod.Post, new { @enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.ID); // Changed this one

    <label>Name: </label>@Html.EditorFor(x => x.Name);

    <button>Submit</button>
}
```

Hope this will help someone save some time and pain.